# Transferring data from CPU to GPU and vice versa where exactly?

Tags: cuda, gpu, cpu

I understand that `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy` transfer CPU (host) data to GPU (device), but I want to know exactly from which memory to which memory (if indeed it is a memory and not a register, because I'm not sure), because I read that a GPU has more than one kind of memory.

Answer (score 2):

The cudaMalloc function allocates a requested number of bytes in Device global memory of the GPU and gives back the initialised pointer to that chunk of memory.
cudaMemcpy takes 4 parameters:

1. Address of pointer to the destination memory where the 
   copy is to be done.
2. Source address
3. Number of bytes
4. The direction of copy  i.e. Host to device or device to host.

For example

```
void Add(float *A, float *B, float *C, int n)
{

    int size = n * sizeof(float);
    float *d_A, *d_B, *d_C;
    cudaMalloc((void**) &d_A, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &d_B, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B, B, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &d_C, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_C, C, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

     // further processing code
       ........

    cudaMemcpy(C, d_C, size, cudaMemcopyDeviceToHost);

     .......

}
```

cudaMemcpyHostToDevice and cudaMemcopyDeviceToHost are constants defined in CUDA programming environment.

In CUDA, host and device have separate memory spaces. GPUs have on board DRAM and some boards may have more than 4 GB of DRAM on, it is known as Device Global Memory. To execute a kernel on a device, the programmer needs to allocate Device Global Memory and transfer the relevant data from host to device memory. After the GPU processing is done the result is transferred back to the Host. These operations are shown in the code snippet above.